# Unable to resolve class of library in splitted Gradle Build Script

Tags: android, android-studio, build, gradle, split

I´m trying to split my Gradle Build file into several parts to make it maintainable

In my build.gradle, I have used the **Apache Commons** library in one task, which I put now in a separate Gradle file

Gradle Project File:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Gradle Module File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: 'gradle/splittedFile.gradle'
```

My splittedFile.gradle

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

> When I execute the build, it says "Unable to resolve class
>   org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

**How can I make the library accessible within the splitted Gradle file?**

Answer (score 5):

Add `buildscript` dependency block to the your `gradle/splittedFile.gradle` file.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2'
    }
}

task encode << {
    def byte[] encodedString = new Base64().encode('hello world\n'.getBytes())
    println new String(encodedString)
}
```